# Accessing global configuration of another middleware directly from a middleware

Tags: python, wsgi, python-paste

I am using python-paste for my apps and my middleware and I am trying to access the configuration of other middlewares directly from that middleware.

There is global_config which access the [DEFAULT] and local_config for the middleware own cofiguration but is there anything for accessing configuration of others without having to parse the file itself in my middleware?

Comment: The term middleware is used a lot, what are you referring to? Specifically "other middlewares"? And why wouldn't you want to parse `global_config`(file) for information when it's in there?

Comment: i am not talking the context of paste so in WSGI where you have multiple middleware plugged together,the global_config has information in DEFAULT not for the other middlewarses.